# Obscure / encrypt an order of words with a three digit number as a key to encrypt / decrypt?

Tags: encryption

1. A user selects 7 random words. The user arranges the words in a random order.
2. Assume these words and their order are important to the user. Each word and it's position / order are important for the user to store securely.

Problem: The user wants to be able to encrypt & decrypt ONLY the order of these words using a "key". That "key" can be any number from 1-999 that the user will memorize.

Ideal Use Cases:

---Put Into Storage---
The user would take their memorized number from 1-999 to do a math problem to encrypt the order of the words, then write the words down in the encrypted order in a notepad.

---Pull Out of Storage---
The user would take their notepad and do another math problem to decrypt the order of the words, then write down the correct order of the words on a new notepad to now have the correct order of the words.

Criteria for a solution:
Assume the user only has a simple calculator to use and no computer to encrypt / decrypt. The user only has basic algebra knowledge. The user is competent enough to follow basic instructions on how to apply their "numeric key" to encrypt / decrypt the order of the words.

Known Pitfalls:
I realize that the total combinations of these 7 random words is 7! = 5040 which could be discovered via brute force hack if intruders wanted to get the correct word order. The brute force argument is known and is an acceptable risk tolerance for this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. As SO is not a code writing service kindly edit your question and add the code you have written so far and struggling with. Please edit the tags as well and append the framework you are working with, thank you.

Comment: This is not a good idea.  As you say, there are 5040 possible word orders, but your three digit key only has 1000 possible values.  That means with a three digit key you can never access 4040 possible word orders.  A three letter key gives over 17,000 possible keys, more than enough to cover all possible word orders.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @rossum. I think your logic of "this is not a good idea" was addressed in the section "known pitfalls". It may not be a good idea but I'm looking for a solution to the problem regardless. I'd like the solution to work for perhaps an 80 word list as well. In this case, the numbers are increased exponentially which would perhaps allow us to ignore the pitfalls.

Comment: With 80 words you have 80! different orderings.  You are better off just using AES to encrypt 80 words of text.  It might help if we knew why you want to do this.  That way it will be easier for us to help you.